# How to remove special characters with regex instead of Replace string

Tags: c#, regex

My current method:

```
var q = new StringBuilder(query);
        return q.Replace("'", " ")
            .Replace("\"", " ")
            .Replace(":", "")
            .Replace("#", " ")
            .Replace("/", " ")
            .Replace("\\", " ")
            .Replace(",", " ")
            .Replace("&", " ")
            .Replace("?", " ")
            .Replace("%", " ")
            .Replace(".", " ")
            .Replace("quot;", " ")
            .Replace("-", " ")
            .Replace("*", " ")
            .ToString().Trim();
```

How can I done this using regex for better performance?

Edited: Sorry, I want replace all special characters by space " ".

Answer (score 5):

You could use this:

```
string q = Regex.Replace(query, @"[:#/\\]", ".");
q = Regex.Replace(q, @"&quot;|['"",&?%\.*-]", " ");
```

## EDIT:

On closer inspection of what you're doing, your code is translating several characters into `.`, and *then* translating all `.` into spaces. So you could just do this:

```
string q = Regex.Replace(query, @"&quot;|['"",&?%\.*:#/\\-]", " ").Trim();
```

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here, though. I feel like what you're **really** looking for is something like:

```
string q = Regex.Replace(query, @"[^\w\s]", "");
```

The presence of `&quot;` in there throws me for a loop, and is why I'm not sure what you're doing. If you want to get rid of HTML entities, you could run `query` through `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(string)` first and then apply the regex.

Comment: +1, but you just translated OP code; `"quot;"` should be `&quot;`, or `&\w+;`

Comment: @RubensFarias - I didn't want to guess too much about what he was doing, but that's a good point. Edited. The old version would have turned `&quot;` into two spaces instead of one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
string pattern = @"[^a-zA-Z0-9]";            
string test = Regex.Replace("abc*&34567*opdldld(aododod';", pattern, " ");
```